# Group data hierarchically on two levels, then compute relative frequencies in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to do something which appears simple, but I don't have a good feel for R yet, it is a maze of twisty passages, all different.

I have a table with several variables, and I want to group on two variables ... I want a two-level hierarchical grouping, also known as a tree. This can evidently be done using the [group_by](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/group_by) function of [dplyr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8).

And then I want to compute marginal statistics (in this case, relative frequencies) based on group counts for level 1 and level 2.

In pictures, given this table of 18 rows:

[image: table we have]

I want this table of 6 rows:

[image: table we want]

Is there a simple way to do this in dplyr? (I can do it in SQL, but ...)

**Edited for example**

For example, based on the `nycflights13` package:

```
library(dplyr)
install.packages("nycflights13")
require(nycflights13)
data(flights) # contains information about flights, one flight per row
ff <- flights %>% 
      mutate(approx_dist = floor((distance + 999)/1000)*1000) %>%
      select(carrier, approx_dist) %>%
      group_by(carrier, approx_dist) %>% 
      summarise(n = n()) %>% 
      arrange(carrier, approx_dist)
```

This creates a tbl `ff` with the number of flights for each pair of (carrier, inter-airport-distance-rounded-to-1000s):

```
# A tibble: 33 x 3
# Groups:   carrier [16]
   carrier approx_dist     n
   <chr>         <dbl> <int>
 1 9E             1000 15740
 2 9E             2000  2720
 3 AA             1000  9146
 4 AA             2000 17210
 5 AA             3000  6373
```

And now I would like to compute the relative frequencies for the "approx_dist" values in each "carrier" group, for example, I would like to get:

```
   carrier approx_dist     n   rel_freq
   <chr>         <dbl> <int> 
 1 9E             1000 15740   15740/(15740+2720)
 2 9E             2000  2720    2720/(15740+2720)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Sample data we can copy/paste into R and test with is more helpful than pictures.

Comment: @MrFlick Okay, I will do that. It's such a simple question though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, here is what you can do. This is not to exactly solve your problem (we don't have the data), but to give you some hints:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- data.frame(col1= rep(c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),2),
                col2 = rep(c("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3"),2),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

d %>% group_by(col1) %>% mutate(count_g1 = n()) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(col1, col2) %>% summarise(rel_freq = n()/unique(count_g1)) %>% ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# col1  col2  rel_freq
# <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
#   1 a     a1       0.333
# 2 a     a2       0.333
# 3 a     a3       0.333
# 4 b     b1       0.333
# 5 b     b2       0.333
# 6 b     b3       0.333
```

**Update:** @TimTeaFan's suggestion on how to re-write the code above using [`prop.table`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/prop.table)

```
d %>% group_by(col1, col2) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% mutate(freq = prop.table(n))
```

**Update:** Running this trick on the `ff` table given in the question's example, which has everything set up except the last `mutate`:

```
ff %>% mutate(rel_freq = prop.table(n))
# A tibble: 33 x 4
# Groups:   carrier [16]
   carrier approx_dist     n rel_freq
   <chr>         <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
 1 9E             1000 15740    0.853
 2 9E             2000  2720    0.147
 3 AA             1000  9146    0.279
 4 AA             2000 17210    0.526
 5 AA             3000  6373    0.195
 6 AS             3000   714    1    
 7 B6             1000 24613    0.450
 8 B6             2000 22159    0.406
 9 B6             3000  7863    0.144
10 DL             1000 20014    0.416
# … with 23 more rows
```

...or

```
ff %>% mutate(rel_freq = n/sum(n))
```

Comment: You could save a few pipes using `prop.table`: 
d %>% 
  group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(freq = prop.table(n))

Comment: Magic. The key is to realize that 1) information about the grouping is actually kept (the intuition from SQL would be that a grouped result does not retain information about the grouping) and that _"When you group by multiple variables, each summary peels off one level of the grouping. That makes it easy to progressively roll-up a dataset."_ (from the `dplyr` vignette). Once one searches for that string, similar questions can be found...

Answer (score 1):

Fake data for demonstration:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
             col1 = rep(c("A","B"), each = 9),
             col2 = rep(1:3),
             value = 1:18)

#> df
#  col1 col2 value
#1     A    1     1
#2     A    2     2
#3     A    3     3
#4     A    1     4
#5     A    2     5
#6     A    3     6
#7     A    1     7
#8     A    2     8
#9     A    3     9
#10    B    1    10
#11    B    2    11
#12    B    3    12
#13    B    1    13
#14    B    2    14
#15    B    3    15
#16    B    1    16
#17    B    2    17
#18    B    3    18
```

Solution

```
df %>%
  group_by(col1, col2) %>%
  summarise(col2_ttl = sum(value)) %>%  # Count is boring for this data, but you 
  mutate(share_of_col1 = col2_ttl / sum(col2_ttl))  #... could use `n()` for that
## A tibble: 6 x 4
## Groups:   col1 [2]
#  col1   col2 col2_ttl share_of_col1
#  <chr> <int>    <int>         <dbl>
#1 A         1       12         0.267
#2 A         2       15         0.333
#3 A         3       18         0.4  
#4 B         1       39         0.310
#5 B         2       42         0.333
#6 B         3       45         0.357
```

First we group by both columns. In this case, the ordering makes a difference, because the groups are created hierarchically, and each summary we run summarizes the last layer of grouping. So the `summarise` line (or `summarize`, it was written with UK spelling but with US spelling aliases) sums up the values in each col1-col2 combination, leaving a residual grouping by col1 which we can use in the next line. (Try putting a `#` after `sum(value))` to see what is produced at that stage.)

In the last line, the `col2_ttl` is divided by the sum of all the `col2_ttl` in its group, ie the total across each `col1`.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I finally got it. But why is the last `mutate()` retaining the group `col1`?

Comment: `group_by` creates groupings. `summarize` peels off the last one and summarizes the group into one number. `mutate` is "group-aware" but doesn't create or reduce groupings.